# Open Edx using IBM cloud distribution

Tags: ibm-cloud, openedx

I am new to openEDX and if this is not right place to ask this question, please feel free to redirect.

I used "Try IBM's Distribution" for openEDX 
[link:https://open.edx.org/get-started/get-started-self-managed]
[option provided under GET STARTED>self managed>choose your distribution]

I went through the steps directed by IBM pop up and it did create a instance of kubenetes cluster in IBM cloud. It is running successfully.

1.And then what ?
2.What should I do to view open EDX site?

Comment: I hope you could get this working. You will have to visit the public IP of your IBM Cloud VM

Comment: @GauravOjha: Thanks Gaurav for taking time to answer. I did visit the public IP address and it still did not work.

Comment: I just gave it a try and at the end of the guided process, I got a statement saying "Your instance will be available at https://xyz123abc.openedx.site within 30 minutes." - guess that's how it is supposed to be deployed.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a bit late but I also tried IBM's Distribution for openEDX recently and did not receive an email with login details. I did the following to access the site:

1. Log into IBM Cloud.
2. Under Resource summary on the dashboard, click **clusters**.
3. Under Clusters, click **mycluster**.
4. Click **Kubernetes Dashboard**.
5. Switch the **namespace** to **open-edx-trial** on the left under Overview.
6. Click **Config Maps** under **Config and Storage**.
7. If you click on **openedx-config**, go through the default set-up environment values and check for **LMS_ROOT_URL** and **CMS_ROOT_URL** for the URL for accessing the deployed site.

To reset the the default password

1. still under the **open-edx-trial** namespace click on **pods**
2. Click on the 3 dots beside the **mysql pod** and select **Exec**
3. From the mysql shell update the **password** and **is_active** fields for the user in the **auth_user** table

You should now be able to login.
Check https://support.skillsnetwork.site/knowledgebase/articles/all for more help.